# Python string.replace() not replacing characters

Tags: python, string, str-replace

Some background information: We have an ancient web-based document database system where I work, almost entirely consisting of MS Office documents with the "normal" extensions (.doc, .xls, .ppt). They are all named based on some sort of arbitrary ID number (i.e. 1245.doc). We're switching to SharePoint and I need to rename all of these files and sort them into folders. I have a CSV file with all sorts of information (like which ID number corresponds to which document's title), so I'm using it to rename these files. I've written a short Python script that renames the ID number title.

However, some of the titles of the documents have slashes and other possibly bad characters to have in a title of a file, so I want to replace them with underscores:

```
bad_characters = ["/", "\\", ":", "(", ")", "<", ">", "|", "?", "*"]
for letter in bad_characters:
    filename = line[2].replace(letter, "_")
    foldername = line[5].replace(letter, "_")
```

- Example of `line[2]`: "Blah blah boring - meeting 2/19/2008.doc"
- Example of `line[5]`: "Business meetings 2/2008"

When I add `print letter` inside of the `for` loop, it will print out the letter it's supposed to be replacing, but won't actually replace that character with an underscore like I want it to.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Tangential question: have you considered doing this with a regular expression?

Comment: @all - Thanks for the explanations. Can't believe I overlooked that. (thursdays...)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's because `filename` and `foldername` get thrown away with each iteration of the loop. The `.replace()` method returns a string, but you're not saving the result anywhere.

You should use:

```
filename = line[2]
foldername = line[5]

for letter in bad_characters:
    filename = filename.replace(letter, "_")
    foldername = foldername.replace(letter, "_")
```

But I would do it using regex. It's cleaner and (likely) faster:

```
p = re.compile('[/:()<>|?*]|(\\\)')
filename = p.sub('_', line[2])
folder = p.sub('_', line[5])
```

Comment: There may be a reason not to change line[2] and line[5]

Answer (score 6):

You are reassigning to the `filename` and `foldername` variables at every iteration of the loop.  In effect, only `*` is being replaced.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the python string method `translate()`
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate
with
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans

Editing this to add an example as per comment suggestion below:

```
import string
toreplace=''.join(["/", "\\", ":", "(", ")", "<", ">", "|", "?", "*"]) 
underscore=''.join( ['_'] * len(toreplace))
transtable = string.maketrans(toreplace,underscore)
filename = filename.translate(transtable)
foldername = foldername.translate(transtable)
```

Can simplify by making the toreplace something like '/\:,'  etc, i just used what was given above

Comment: could you give example in current context ?

Answer (score 3):

You are starting over with the base line instead of saving the replaced result, thus you are getting the equivalent to

```
filename = line[2].replace('*', '_')
foldername = line[5].replace('*', '_')
```

Try the following

```
bad_characters = ["/", "\\", ":", "(", ")", "<", ">", "|", "?", "*"]
filename = line[2]
foldername = line[5]
for letter in bad_characters:
    filename = filename.replace(letter, "_")
    foldername = foldername.replace(letter, "_")
```

Answer (score 1):

Should use string.replace(str, fromStr, toStr)

```
bad_characters = ["/", "\\", ":", "(", ")", "<", ">", "|", "?", "*"]
for letter in bad_characters:
    filename = string.replace(line[2], letter, "_")
    foldername = string.replace(line[5], letter, "_")
```